# ¿Por qué el operador OR no da resultado en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Necesito su ayuda para despejar una dudas por favor, estoy aprendiendo base de datos en MySQL y me he topado con un problemita, tengo esta tabla de clientes y su país(región) cuando utilizo el operador OR de la siguiente manera :

```
select * from Costumers where Region='Peru' or 'Africa';
```

Me da los valores en los cuales el país es Peru, hasta ahí todo bien (Puse África a propósito sabiendo que esa proposición es falsa ya que África no existe en mi tabla y sabiendo que al ser verdadera la primera proposición ya no evaluara la segunda)
sin embargo cuando cambio el orden de las proposiciones ya no me arroja resultado alguno

```
select * from Costumers where Region= 'Africa' or 'Peru';
```

En este caso no me arroja nada, entiendo que si no se cumple la primera proposición es decir que el país sea África, entonces debería pasar a las segunda proposición y arrojarme los datos para los paises que sean Perú pero no sale nada, ayúdenme explicando por que sucede eso por favor, estaré muy agradecido.

[image: Mi tabla Costumers]

Comment: También puedes usar el operador `in()`. Ej. `Region in('Africa','Perú')`.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 5):

Tu consulta debe ser:

```
select * from Costumers where Region= 'Africa' or Region = 'Peru';
```

Un saludo

Comment: Estaría bien que editases la respuesta aclarando por qué has de poner Region en cada condición del where porque esta respuesta podría ser considerada un comentario

Comment: Gracias por el aviso. Tomaré nota. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda me sirvió de mucho

Answer (score 4):

Bueno el compañero ya explico el tema del problema con la sintaxis de MySQL, pero yo vengo a aclara un punto sobre tu postulado y cito:

> Puse África a propósito sabiendo que esa proposición es falsa ya que África no existe en mi tabla y sabiendo que al ser verdadera la primera proposición ya no evaluara la segunda

Esto es incorrecto ya que los operadores AND Y OR evalúan dos proposiciones, las tablas de verdad para el operador OR son:

| A | B | A OR B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| V | V | V |
| V | F | V |
| F | V | V |
| F | F | F |

Esto quiere decir en resumen:  **Será verdadero si al menos una de las dos proposiciones es verdadera, de lo contrario será falsa** , entonces para tu caso si África no existiese en la tabla pero Perú si entonces el resultado de la proposición será verdadera y de igual manera a la inversa, si existe África, pero no Perú también sera verdadera y traerá resultados.

| Región = Perú | Región=África | Región = Perú OR Región=África |
| --- | --- | --- |
| V | V | V |
| V | F | V |
| F | V | V |
| F | F | F |

y como indica el colega la sintaxis debe ser:

```
SELECT * FROM Costumers WHERE Region= 'Africa' OR Region = 'Peru';
```

Esto por que la comparación la estas haciendo solo con el primer string Region='String', luego para OR 'String', Desconozco que resultado te arrojará, pero por tus resultados creo que OR 'String' es FALSE.

Comment: Esto es sql... eso no pasa.. porque si no, nunca traeria registros que fueran peru... @Sal

Comment: Muchas gracias, entonces entiendo que la manera como lo escribí estaba mal, gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Como dijo @Sal en su comentario puedes hacer lo siguente, lo cual yo utilizo mucho

```
select * from Costumers where Region IN('Africa','Peru','Ecuador');
```

Con esto le decis a MySql que traiga todos los registros cuya region sea Africa *o* Peru *o* Ecuador, por ende podemos concluir que es equivalente a escribir esto:

```
select * from Costumers where Region = 'Africa' or Region = 'Peru' or Region = 'Ecuador';
```

Comment: Wao no se me había ocurrido eso muchas gracias te pasaste